# Is there an existential version for $ \forall x (\alpha \to \beta) \to (\forall x \alpha \to \forall x \beta) $?

Tags: logic

Enderton's An Mathematical Introduction to Logic presents a logical axiom on p112:

> 2. $$ \forall x (\alpha \to \beta) \to (\forall x \alpha \to \forall x \beta) $$

Why is it? Is it assumed to be true, or is it proved from something else? Since it is a logical axiom, is it assumed to be true?

Is there an existential version for it? For example, is the one below correct?

$$ \exists x (\alpha \to \beta) \to (\exists x \alpha \to \exists x \beta) $$

If not, what is an existential version which is correct?

Comment: Replace all $\forall x$ by $\neg\exists x\neg$.

Comment: @user10354138 is the result $ (\exists x \alpha \to \exists x \beta) \to \exists x (\alpha \to \beta)$?

Comment: See Enderton, page 130.

Comment: In the existential case, it depends on whether you are assuming that $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$ and $\beta$. If $x$ does not occur free then the biconditional holds. If $x$ does occur free, then your relation does not hold, since there is a countermodel as follows: suppose a domain of two elements, $u$, $v$, such that $val(\alpha(u)) = 1, val(\alpha(v)) = 0, val(\beta(u)) = 0, val(\beta(v)) = 0.$

Comment: by definition, an axiom of a formal system is a statement for which there is no proof and that is simply assumed to be true

Comment: @Bumble can  (∃xα→∃xβ)→∃x(α→β) be derived from ∀x(α→β)→(∀xα→∀xβ), by replacing all ∀x by ¬∃x¬?

Comment: The conditional does work in that direction, i.e. $(\exists\alpha x \rightarrow \exists\beta x) \rightarrow \exists(\alpha x \rightarrow \beta x)$

Answer (score 3):

As you know, a statement like 'All P are Q' translates as $$\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))$$

On the other hand, a statement like  'Some P are Q' translates as $$\exists x (P(x) \land Q(x))$$

Hence, I would say the natural existential 'counterpart' of

$$ \forall x (\alpha \to \beta) \to (\forall x \alpha \to \forall x \beta) $$

would be

$$ \exists x (\alpha \land \beta) \to (\exists x \alpha \land \exists x \beta) $$

and that is indeed a logically true principle.

Also note that both principles only work as one-way conditionals. That is, it is not logically true that:

$$(\forall x \alpha \to \forall x \beta) \to \forall x (\alpha \to \beta)  $$

and likewise, it is also not logically true that:

$$ (\exists x \alpha \land \exists x \beta)  \to \exists x (\alpha \land \beta)$$

Comment: Thanks @sambo! :)

Comment: From p131 Exercise 17 and 16, it looks like there are more natural forall counterpart of ∃x(α∧β)→(∃xα∧∃xβ) than ∀x(α→β)→(∀xα→∀xβ)

Comment: @Tim I don’t have the book …

Answer (score 1):

I decided to post a full version of my comment to buttress Bram28’s answer.

While Bram’s answer provides a natural-language counterpart to the distribution axiom, my example provides an axiom that could replace $\forall x (\phi \to \psi) \to (\forall x \phi \to \forall x \phi)$ in the system you mention.

The new axiom is:

$(\exists x A \lor \exists x B) \leftrightarrow \exists x (A \lor B)$

Here’s a brief sketch of the derivability of the former axiom from its existential counterpart:

1. $\vdash (\exists x \neg (\phi \to \psi) \lor \exists x \neg \phi) \leftrightarrow \exists x (\neg (\phi \to \psi) \lor \neg \phi)$
   [New Axiom]
2. $\vdash (\forall x  (\phi \to \psi) \land \forall x \phi) \leftrightarrow \forall x ((\phi \to \psi) \land \phi)$ [1, Classical Logic, def. of $\exists$]
3. $\vdash (\forall x  (\phi \to \psi) \land \forall x \phi) \to \forall x \psi$ [2]

Note that the step from line 2 to line 3 requires the use of the new axiom.

Comment: Thanks. What is your existential counterpart?

Comment: Is line 1 the succinct form of the new axiom?

Comment: Yes I must have forgotten to include it before the proof. I’ll edit it.